# Laravel Many-to-Many Relationship Field Names

Tags: laravel, eloquent, eloquent-relationship

I have a users table and a permissions table. One user can have many permissions, and one permission can have many users:

```
USER ID | PERMISSION ID
1 | 1
1 | 2
2 | 1
2 | 1
```

There is a linking table called permission_user as defined by the Laravel spec for auto-inferring these tables.

If I define the following functions:

User Model:

```php
    public function Permissions()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Permission');
    }
```

Permission Model:

```php
   public function Users()
   {
       return $this->belongsToMany('App\User');
   }
```

I get an error when calling `App\User::first()->Permissions()->attach(App\Permission::first());` that says

```
 Illuminate\Database\QueryException  : SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '' in 'field list' (SQL: insert into `permission_user` (``, `user_id`) values (3, 1))
```

The database migration file:

```php
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Carbon\Carbon;
use App\User;
use App\Permission;
use App\Http\Resources\User as UserResource;
class CreateUsersTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('permissions', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->timestamps();
        });

        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('username')->unique();
            $table->string('name')->unique();
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->boolean('verified');
            $table->timestamps();
        });


        Schema::create('permission_user', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('permission_id');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->foreign('permission_id')->references('id')->on('permissions');
            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
        });

        $this->add_permission('View Projects');
        $this->add_permission('Edit Projects');
        $this->add_permission('View Users');
        $this->add_permission('Edit Users');

        $user = new User();
        $user->name = 'John Smith';
        $user->email = 'john@smith.com';
        $user->username = 'jsmith';
        $user->verified = 1;
        $user->save();


        $user->permissions()->attach(Permission::where('name','View Users')->first()->id); // -> This line it can't tell that permission_user.permission_id is where the permission.id field goes;

        $perms  = $user->permissions()->get();

        foreach($perms as $perm)
        {
            echo $perm->name . '\n';
        }

    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        DB::statement('SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0');
        Schema::dropIfExists('permission_user');
        Schema::dropIfExists('project_user');
        Schema::dropIfExists('permissions');
        Schema::dropIfExists('deployment_log');
        Schema::dropIfExists('branches');
        Schema::dropIfExists('projects');
        Schema::dropIfExists('users');
        DB::statement('SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1');
    }

    private function add_permission($permission_name)
    {
        DB::table('permissions')->insert(
            array(
                'name' => $permission_name,
            )
        );
    }
}
```

It appears Laravel(5.8) is unable to disscern from the linking table that permission_id is the field for the foreign reference to the permission.id field even though the database migration reflects that user_id is a foreign reference to user.id and permission_id is a foreign reference to permission.id.

I can solve this by specifying the linking table name, field name, and foreign key name in the belongsToMany function, however, Laravel's own documentation states that this isn't needed when tables and fields are named appropriately, which mine are. Is this a bug in Laravel? Do I need to change the name of the permission_user.permission_id field? How do I solve this without having to specify these names in my models as it's time consuming and not needed according to Laravel(5.8)'s documentation.

Comment: Do the permissions exist in your database? Are they actual stored?

Comment: Did you tried it with the `permission_user` table containing only the `user_id` and `permission_id` fields, without timestamps and id? Also, set both `user_id` and `permission_id` as the primary key for this table.

Comment: Can you post your complete permission model?

Comment: @MateusJunges Looks like that solved it. I had a primary key id on the linking table with timestamps, not sure why that would matter as that's something that's pretty standard.

Comment: To work as intended, the linking table must contain only the primary key for each model of your relation. If you need these additional columns, you must specify your relationship table and the primary key for each table while defining the `belongsToMany` relationship.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to laravel docs:

> [...] Many users may have the role of "Admin". To define this relationship, three database tables are needed: `users`, `roles`, and `role_user`. The `role_user` table is derived from the alphabetical order of the related model names, and contains the `user_id` and `role_id` columns.

The linking table must contain only the foreign keys from each model. Otherwise, you need to specify which relationship table you are using and the primary key for each model of the relation, as specified on laravel documentation.

As i said in the comments section, if you create your `permission_user` table with only `permission_id` and `user_id` columns and with this columns as primary keys, it will work as expected:

```php
Schema::create('permission_user', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->unsignedBigInteger('permission_id');
    $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');
    $table->foreign('permission_id')->references('id')->on('permissions');
    $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');

    $table->primary(['permission_id', 'user_id']);
});
```

[Here](https://github.com/mateusjunges/laravel-acl) is a package that i have developed to handle user permissions and you can check the `user_has_permissions` table definition, which is, basically, a table that does exactly what your `permission_user` table does,  by clicking [this link](https://github.com/mateusjunges/laravel-acl/blob/master/src/database/migrations/2019_03_16_005834_create_user_has_groups_table.php).

Hope it helps.